# Windows & Linux living together in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gcloud

I was looking at the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/) which seems to have a windows compability, however I don't find completely clear if both Linux and Windows can live together (I mean, in diferent VMs but the same cluster).

I would like to know if there is any support for this scenario in `gcloud`, `azure` or `aws`. And also, the procedure or example to make it work. Like how to create a pod in the correct VM (windows or linux) and how horizontal and cluster autoscalers work.

The use case is 2 APIs, one running in windows (.NET Framework) and other in linux (python/c++) and I want to be able to reroute them, be able to call each other, scale them and so on with kubernetes. As a note, the `.NET Framework` application have dependencies (mainly for mathematical optimization) that cannot be passed to `.NET Core`, this implies that I cannot convert the application to [linux-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x).

Comment: You can't do this on [Google] Kubernetes Engine today (gcloud). Currently Kubernetes Engine supports only Linux VMs. I'm unaware of (this doesn't infer that there aren't) any plans to support one cluster with multiple OSs.

Comment: An alternative solution would be for you to deploy your .NET runtimes to Linux (!) containers running on a Linux-only Kubernetes platform. .NET works great on Linux and, as long as you're able to run your code using this, open-sourced variant, it is something for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @DazWilkin. In fact, I know that it's possible to deploy with `.NET CORE` because of the multi OS compatibility. However, the application has dependencies based on `.NET Framework` which is only supported by Windows.

Comment: Got it! Let me ask around and get you a more definitive answer for Kubernetes Engine's plans.

Comment: And your .NET dependency is a binary, obfuscated, closed source DLL? If not, what class is not portable? Perhaps, you can mend it to be portable one.

Comment: I would really want to know for a general case, not a particular one. Because it's a code which I don't control, it's another programmer. However, in our particular case, it seems one of the libraries is [extreme optimization](https://www.extremeoptimization.com/downloads.aspx), but I'm not sure if it's the only one.

Comment: I guess that they don't provide portable .NET is because Windows TPM protects their business. What features do you require from extreme optimization? Is your main platform is python or native linux? Perhaps, others can come up with alternatives.

Comment: I call a lot of linux programs either with bash subprocesses and so on. So yeah, native linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some history, so containers is a Linux thing so there are no containers per se on Windows. Docker created Docker for Windows but essentially what it does is run a Hyper-V Linux VM (used to be VirtualBox) and inside it runs your containers. As of the latest Docker version, Microsoft has added capabilities on Hyper-V to allow running these containers kinda natively making it easy to run [.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc) in containers.

K8s is implemented in Golang so it was generally easier to port main components like the `kubelet`, `kube-proxy`, `kubectl` to Windows, by using the Golang cross-compiler (or native on Windows)

A tricky part is the networking but looks like they've got it figured out in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/#upstream-l3-routing-topology)

As far as public cloud support from major providers:

- AWS

  - Hypervisor:  Modified Xen or KVM. No nested virtualization support.
  - VMs: Windows VMs. Can't take advantage of Hyper-V with nested virtualization, but can run Docker for Windows.
  - Bare-metal: (i3.metal as of this writing). Run Hyper-V natively and Docker for Windows.
- Azure

  - Hypervisor: Hyper-V. Supports nested virtualization on some instance types.
  - VMs: Windows VMs, can use nested virtualization with Hyper-V, and can run Docker for Windows.
  - ACS, AKS, ACE: Should be able to take advantage of Hyper-V with nested virtualization and some cases natively.
- GCP

  - Hypervisor: KVM. Supports nested virtualization on some instance types.
  - VMs: Windows VMs. Can run Hyper-V with nested virtualization and can run Docker for Windows.

Other than that I don't know what else there's to it (Other than what's in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/)) The question is very broad. Just install Docker for Windows, setup networking, join your cluster with `kubeadm` and schedule your Windows workloads using the `nodeSelector` spec in your pods and make sure you label your Windows nodes with `beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows`

There's another good guide on to set up Kubernetes with Windows nodes [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=E2B6765015E5FA01!339&ithint=file%2Cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AGvs_s_hWs7xHGs)

Comment: This is an interesting answer. I knew windows used Hyper-V for the linux virtual machine that runs docker, but I didn't know for windows it uses the same. Also, I saw the network process in the documenation, however I didn't see anything about the automation (maybe some lack of experience on my side?). The label `beta.kubernetes.io/os=windows` is defenetly something I didn't know. And finally, it would be nice to know about compatibilities with aws, azure and/or gcloud.

Comment: Added more details for the major cloud providers

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, your answer is pretty complete, interesting and neat. I hope the guys at gcloud, aws and azure work to do a straight forward way to do it. Because as far as I can see, the solution implies to make a lot of scripts that are going to control stuff such as scaling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should be possible.

Since all the deployments live in docker containers you can run any OS on Kubernetes (in a docker container). Also Windows.

Running both Windows and Linux containers on the same cluster shouldn't cause you any problems.

Comment: Thanks @bn4t. However, I'm looking for a more detailed answer. I would like to know how to programatically create nodes and pods targeted to the OS of the image container. How to use hpa autoscaler, cluster autoscaler and so on.